# Looking for a word to describe someone who is famous to a small group of people

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word to describe someone who is famous to a small group of people.

For example I play a competitive card game and there are several people who are famous within the gaming community, but outside of that community they are just your average people. Most people wouldn't recognize them as celebrities.

Comment: In my experience, people tend to use **infamous** with that sense (cf. _The Infamous Swoosh_) even though this does not match the dictionary definition.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Cult Hero** - a writer, musician, artist, or other public figure who is greatly admired by a relatively small audience or is influential despite limited commercial success. [OED](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cult_hero)

Comment: 'hero' might be a bit much in many cases...I fee like they are more often described as "having a cult following" (same general answer as you give though)

Comment: Though the google definition appears to suffice for the requirement, _cult icon_ is an alternative as used in the [Wikipedia article on cult following](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_following).

Comment: Pretty sure Google didn't come up with that definition...

Comment: Or "Cult Figure"? https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cult_figure

Comment: I think 'Cult Icon' or 'Cult Figure' are more common, especially outside of the folklore community. ;)

Comment: I got "cult hero" from soccer. It's what you call an average player who occassionally has a moment of magic, and so is adored by some fans of the team.

Answer (score 28):

You could use the idiom "***a big fish in a small pond***" to describe the person.

> a big fish in a small pond:  one of the most important people in a small group or organization, who would have much less power and importance if they were part of a larger group or organization ([Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+big+fish+in+a+small+pond)).

[image]
http://www.azquotes.com/quote/21985

Comment: If it weren't for the OP asking specifically for a single word, this is what I would have voted for.

Comment: @hatchet -- Granted, but currently all the other options are multi-word answers, too, and perhaps there isn't a good single word option?

Comment: This has a slight negative bent that I don't believe was intended--it usually implies that the big fish is deliberately staying in the small pond in order to enjoy his prominence.

Comment: Since the OP has accepted an answer that isn't a single word, I suppose that wasn't an important criterion, so here's my upvote after all.

Comment: I agree with @Bill K. This idiom implies the subject could escape to a larger enclosure at their will, which is not the case for the situation OP describes.

Comment: This is not a good answer to OP's request. "A big fish in a small pond" primarily means that the relative importance or status of the target is exaggerated by the smallness or unimportance of the context. It commonly implies that the target could choose to be part of a larger pond, which makes little sense for someone who is defined by what they do in a highly specific or unique area. The idiom is also arguably less about fame and more about relative influence or performance. It would seem that performance or status are more context-dependent than the number of one's admirers.

Answer (score 22):

A word of arguable authority (apparently absent from major dictionaries, although used by mainstream publications), is **[demicelebrity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demicelebrity)**.

> **demicelebrity**
>
> 1. *uncountable* Minor fame
> 2. *countable* A minor celebrity; a person of restricted fame

[Example of use from Newsweek](http://www.newsweek.com/come-fly-him-123687):

> Is the life of a **demicelebrity** like Schwartz worth reading about?
>   Absolutely.

[Example of use from Boston Magazine](http://www.bostonmagazine.com/arts-entertainment/blog/2014/04/16/pizza-underground-macaulay-culkin/):

> What does it mean for such a **demi-celebrity** to tell a reporter that
>   their very silly project—one completely unrelated to the thing for
>   which he is famous...

Use in the book The [Star of Istanbul](https://books.google.com/books?id=NJmQutgArPkC&pg=PT33&lpg=PT33&dq=%22demicelebrity%22&source=bl&ots=tCSIkAYqa1&sig=hVO6fOS8IjCUf1dzufORpN8SLKk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie4rLwz5PVAhUH4WMKHUuKCa44ChDoAQgmMAE#v=onepage&q=%22demicelebrity%22&f=false):

> And so a famous mother could be helpful, given Selene's apparent
>   obliviousness to my own wide **demicelebrity** among Chicago cabdrivers
>   and shoe shine boys and shop owners...all of whom knew my name pretty
>   well.

Comment: Surely a demicelebrity would be, by analogy with a demigod, the child of a celebrity and a normal person.

Comment: "micro-celebrity" would be a more appropriate term, and more popular (at least, in my experience).

Answer (score 19):

You could say these people have a **[niche](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+niche) following**:

> denoting or relating to products, services, or interests that appeal to a small, specialized section of the population.

*"Person XYZ has a niche following in the gaming community."*

Comment: Haven't heard it used before, but I imagine **niche celebrity** would be well understood.

Comment: @BradC Yeah, that sounds fine to me.

Comment: I think this gets closer to the desired meaning than many other answers. In particular, a cult is usually not restricted to a small group of people. With a *niche* though, the person's followers may be devoted and numerous within their peer group, but by definition only there. Examples include fringe areas in all cultural domains (music, fine or not-so-fine arts, film, manga, fashion, food, even porn or zen gardening).

Answer (score 12):

Try this concatenated phrase:

"micro-notoriety"

Usage: "... Within the team, Carter has achieved a certain level of micro-notoriety...".

Source:  Used in [Guide to the Cinema of Stephen King](https://books.google.com/books?id=6t2pDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=micro-notoriety&source=bl&ots=EHjCwZDnp-&sig=MY0TGd4gv0HtqysW7jpjgfLHN-M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj80c-YzJPVAhVDrD4KHfQ3AIA4ChDoAQglMAA#v=onepage&q=micro-notoriety&f=false), by Caputo.

Comment: I was going to give the "Big Fish, Small Pond" answer. (Thomj1332 beat me to it), but I found this to be an innovative solution. +1

Comment: I hadn't heard this term before, but it does seem to be in circulation. This answer would help more future visitors if you'd edit it to provide some documentation showing it's used in the wild.

Comment: I like micro-notoriety. It has a nerdy panache to it.

Comment: @M.Mat I like nerdy panache.  It has a je ne sais quoi to it.

Answer (score 8):

You can get a very specific version of this by prepending the specific interest or locality in which the individual is famous.

For localities:

- London-famous
- Rochdale-famous
- Valley-famous

For interest groups:

- Youtube-famous
- Ruby-famous
- Yo-yo-famous

These aren't standard English words, or even single words, really, but they will largely be understood as meaning 'famous' but for that specific niche.

Answer (score 6):

**Local Hero** - you can also enjoy [a nice film with the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Hero).

Answer (score 4):

Semi-renowned?

In Halifax, Nova Scotia, they say someone is "Halifamous" :)

Source for Halifamous:  [The Coast, Halifax's website](https://www.thecoast.ca/halifax/how-to-be-halifamous/Content?oid=1819385)

Comment: Is this actually correct throughout the whole city? Is it documented anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

I lean toward the use of "**royalty**", prefacing it with the specific community in mind.

> 1.3 "The most successful, famous, or highly regarded members of a particular group." ([oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/royalty))

Actually, most of the other answers will also work in the same fashion, but I think this feels most natural.

> - World Poker royalty
> - Xtreme Sports royalty
> - Beverly Hills-adjacent, above-Sunset, 2nd generation Persian-Jewish      royalty
> - Food Network royalty
> - Washington High, Class of '73 royalty

This fits neatly into the "big fish in a small/specific pond" idea

Answer (score 1):

"*Noteworthy*" or "*Of note*" would suffice. While not strictly required a context is usually provided as "he is a bridge player of note" or "his writings on bridge are noteworthy".

"*Notorious*" is of the same derivation but has incurred negative connotations.

Answer (score 0):

**esoteric**:

> intended for or likely to be understood by only a small number of people with a specialized knowledge or interest.

<sup>[oxford dictionaries online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/esoteric)</sup>

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please cite your sources; we don't like plagiarism here.

Comment: Can you give an example of this being used to describe a person rather than knowledge, a debate, etc?

Answer (score -1):

**relatively famous** is the term that popped into my mind.

But it might be relatively applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I was telling someone about meeting a person who a lot of people with my hobby watch on YouTube but who outsiders wouldn't know.  I didn't know how else to explain it, so I called him "internet famous."

Answer (score -3):

**Legend** totally works for somebody who's accomplished impressive feats (like winning many of these card game tournaments).

Answer (score -4):

I am afraid it is not an established expression but I still would propose "pocket universe deity" as it is still reasonably succinct and descriptive.

The word "demigod" is also sometimes employed with similar meaning, but even when used in the non-literal sense it often refers rather to a limit in rank rather than scope.

Comment: Never heard of 'pocket universe deity' - where does it come from? Also, they are borderline not really answering the question, you may want to explain why 'famous' means 'worshiped' (if it does)