# A word for a non-famous person/thing you have heard a lot about

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Someone or something you have heard a lot about. Not really a widely known person, but a friend of a friend or a local person (from your school/workplace/..). A thing you have discussed before, but is not well-known to outsiders.

Similar question: [Looking for a word to describe someone who is famous to a small group of people](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/400545/looking-for-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-is-famous-to-a-small-group-of-people)

**Cult hero** from above question does **NOT** apply, and the best fit is the awkward and nondescript **demicelebrity**.

---

In my experience, people tend to colloquially use **infamous** with that sense (cf. *The Infamous Swoosh*) even though this *does not match the dictionary definition*.

> **infamous**: well known for some bad quality or deed

I think peeps use **infamous** because they think of the word **famous**, but would feel silly using **famous** (the object in question has a more limited sort of "fame"). **Familiar** is close but not quite specific and expressive enough.

---

Contrived example:

> I can't wait to meet your son Logan! I've heard so much (good stuff) about him! He's ________ [= well-known to me].

Actual examples from me texting:

```
> Me: https://68.media.tumblr.com/0dc47d322a9f8615dada2510ce522d20/tumblr_ojpmf5nYc41uy57v5o1_400.jpg
> Them: lol, I thought about the fast-food chains first, too!
> Me: i thought about Domains in the context of haskell
> Me: the infamous 'Dom' chain >_>

> [talking about modular smartphones]
> Me: that black guy from yesterday even has a video on them
> Me: next to techaltar's infamous video on them
```

---

What would be a better fit in this situation? Or am I stuck with **demi-famous**?

Comment: local/minor/niche celebrity, or  someone locally famous could be described as a "local identity".

Comment: Logan is *highly-regarded*.

Comment: The *never-ending* 'Dom' chain.

Comment: Wouldn't you use *viral* for a video, even if it wasn't really that famous?

Answer (score 4):

If I knew somebody wasn't famous objectively, but I kept hearing about them from people I met, I might say that—within my social group at least—they were [ubiquitous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ubiquitous).

> existing or being everywhere at the same time : constantly encountered : widespread · a *ubiquitous* fashion
>
> seeming to be seen everywhere

In other words, not necessarily famous, but still the "talk of the town."

Comment: The best I could come up with was 'notorious' which wasn't quite correct. I think you've got it.